# why nginx must run as root user?

Tags: sockets, nginx, root

When I start nginx, I can see that actually two processes running, 
one of them is root and another one runs as user from config. file.

I understand that nginx needs root priveleges to open port 80, but it could also open that port as root and then do setuid(),
the socket descriptor stays available. After all we start nginx as root, only for the reason it can open 80 port and create pid and log files, but than we don't need root process any more. The process doesn't have to stay root, or am I missing something?

What is this root process good for?

Comment: Nginx could reload config without restarting, so it still need root privileges. Also this process manages worker processes (kills/restarts them as needed)

Comment: For starting and killing processes you don't have to be root.